# Elasticsearch truncate response

Tags: python, json, search, elasticsearch

Is it possible to truncate the value in an elasticsearch response? I want the full description in ES in order to make it searchable but I don't want to return more than 200 chars in the response.

Is this something elasticsearch can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want the portion of data that fits the query you should have a look at [Highlighting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html). Unfortunately, you have to change your index mapping in order to index the data with position offsets.

At query time, you can specify the `fragment_size` that will be returned. The fragment is the data that surrounds your matched query.

Comment: Highlighting is a good option but what about if I only want the first 200 chars (not necessarily the portion that the result is in) returned of the description, regardless of where the term was found within the entire description? Is there a way to limit the result without using highlighting?